# Add button to Config.xml

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I wanted to know if it is possible to add a button to the config.xml. I have read a lot about this but I can't find a clear answer.

Some talk about creating a custom component but it is not explained clearly. For example, in which paths the files should be created, or how it should be done.

I tried https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/administration/add-custom-component.html

and in config xml use

```
<component name="hello-world">
    <name>apiKey</name>
</component>
```

but it does not work

Any idea?